# Edit Flow button missing

Tags: visual-workflow

There is an existing Screen flow in the system and I'd like to make some changes to it. However, the Edit Flow button is missing.

Attached is the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Does your user account have required permissions to edit lightning flows?

Comment: Yes, I am the system admin

Comment: Missed to notice earlier. Aren't already in the flow editor page? Are you unable to edit the flow?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `Edit` button

- If the Flow version hasn't been activated, you can edit the version you opened directly in the canvas. Click `Save` to commit changes.
- If the Flow version has been activated, you can edit the Flow version directly in the canvas but you will need to do a `Save As` to commit the changes to a new version